# What is the length of the 4th side?

Tags: geometry

Given the figure in this image (I don't know the correct name in English. I wish to know the length of the 4th side. How to calculate it and what's the length of the 4th side?

[image]

Comment: Hint: Pythagoras.

Comment: The figure is called a trapezium (UK) or a trapezoid (US).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rule of Pythagoras:
$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

while the line $a$ is prependicular to $b$

In your case you get:
$$?=\sqrt{(310 \text{cm})^2+(300\text{cm}-204\text{cm})^2}=\sqrt{105 315} \text{cm} \approx  325 \text{cm}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: draw this line...............

[image]